# Rundeck failed to remove remote file in C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\ when the Job times out

Tags: rundeck

Notice that when the Rundeck job triggers a timed out due to running too long, it fails to remove the temp file from my remote window node. Due to this action, the Temp folder has an unnecessary amount of dispatch temp files in the folder. I wondered if their a config setting to remove said files if the job triggers a timed out within Rundeck.

Rundeck is running on Community 3.4.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific option for that, a good idea you can do is to run a [periodic](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/document-format-reference/job-v20.html#schedule) job that cleans that directory.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling it was a long shot for that option. Thanks for the insight